# Solution to a matrix valued linear inhomogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

I have an ODE for a vector $\vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} \vec{w}(t) + \frac{\alpha}{n} XX^T \vec{w}(t) = \frac{\alpha}{n} X \vec{y}
$$
where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $\alpha > 0$ is a constant and $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is also constant.
I'm having a hard time constructing an analytical solution from an integration constant. We see that the integration constant is
$$
I(t) = \exp \left( -\int \frac{\alpha }{n} XX^T \text{d}t\right) = \vec{w_0} \exp \left(-\frac{\alpha t}{n} XX^T \right).
$$
I know that the solution is
$$
\vec{w}(t) =  \exp \left(-\frac{\alpha t}{n} XX^T \right) \vec{w_0} + \left(I_n - \exp \left(-\frac{\alpha t}{n} XX^T \right) \right)\left(XX^T\right)^{-1}X\vec{y}
$$
but I get nowhere close to that so I assume my integration constant is false. Perhaps there's another formula for matrix valued function's since I've assume it's the same as a classic first order inhomogenous linear ode.

EDIT: We known that $n < m$.

Comment: Using an integrating factor (dropping vector notation) implies, at least formally (assuming $X$ is a constant matrix) \begin{align}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\alpha t}{n}XX^{T}\right)w\right)'&=\frac{\alpha}{n}\exp\left(\frac{\alpha t}{n}XX^{T}\right)Xy\\\implies \exp\left(\frac{\alpha t}{n}XX^{T}\right)w&=\int\frac{\alpha}{n}\exp\left(\frac{\alpha t}{n}XX^{T}\right)Xydt\\&=\exp\left(\frac{\alpha t}{n}XX^{T}\right)(XX^{T})^{-1}Xy+C\\\implies w&=\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha t}{n}XX^{T}\right)C+(XX^{T})^{-1}Xy\end{align}with $C$ a constant matrix. Evaluating at $w(0)=w_{0}$ yields the result.

Comment: I don't understand how you go $(XX^T)^-1$ in your evaluation of the integral.